# Unbalanced data: Feed-forward deep network with balanced class_weight does not learn beyond the dominant class

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

I have data with 5 output classes. The training data has the following no of samples for these 5 classes: [706326, 32211, 2856, 3050, 901]

I am using the following keras (tf.keras) code:

```
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                 np.unique(y_train),
                                                 y_train)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, input_shape=(dataX.shape[1],)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax) ])
     adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.5)

model.compile(optimizer=adam, 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=[metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy])    
     model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32, class_weight=class_weights)

y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test), axis=1)
```

I am using sparse_categorical_crossentropy which accepts categories as integers (don't need to convert them to one-hot encoding), but I also tried categorical_crossentropy and still the same problem.

I have of course tried different learning rate, batch_size, no of epochs, optimizer, and depth/length of the network. But it always is stuck at ~0.94 accuracy which is essentially I would get if I predict the first class all the time.

Not sure what is missing here. Any error on my part, or some bug with class_weight in Keras? Or should I use some other specialized deep network?

Comment: you should check per class precision/recall values. If they are reasonably good, then your network is considering the class weights when training.

Comment: I checked the confidence matrix. All the classes are predicted as  the dominant class.